# Is $\mathbb{Z}^2/<(1,1)>$ cyclic and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory

I want to study the structure of cokernel of abelian group homomorphism.

Is it true that $\mathbb{Z}^2/<(1,1)>$ is cyclic group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 10):

Let $\varphi\colon\mathbb Z^2\to \mathbb Z$, $\varphi(x,y)=x-y$. Then $\varphi$ is a homomorphism. Since $\ker\varphi = \langle (1,1)\rangle$ and $\varphi$ is surjective, the [first isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem) gives the answer.